# Dollar sign in X-SAMPA

Tags: sampa

A Danish pronounciation dictionary "NST Lexical database for Danish" has an X-SAMPA-like annotation.

In a documentation document at http://www.nb.no/sbfil/leksikalske_databaser/trans_konv/da_transkonv.tar.gz and in the pronounciation dictionary itself http://www.nb.no/sbfil/leksikalske_databaser/leksikon/da_leksikon.tar.gz, I find that the dollar sign ("$") is used as a syllable separator. I also see that "¤" is used as sentence stress ("sætningstryk") indicator.

As I have been using the NST database for Wikidata lexemes for the X-SAMPA property (see, e.g., https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?title=Lexeme:L34765&oldid=1040257932), I am wondering about the dollar sign as a X-SAMPA symbol. I have not seen it anywhere else. Is it a non-standard symbol? Should one erase the dollar sign from X-SAMPA code to avoid that tools that might be using it get confused?

Answer (score 1):

X-SAMPA aims to use the same symbols as IPA whenever they are available. Thus, the symbol for a syllable break is simply `.`, just like in IPA. I don't believe `$` means anything in the actual standard, and `¤` is out of the question as it's not even part of ASCII, which X-SAMPA is restricted to. I'm going to guess it's used in that pronunciation dictionary because Nordic keyboard layouts typically include that symbol, which is rather uncommon on other layouts and largely unused.

Comment: So it seems that one should convert "$" to "." to conform to the standard.

Comment: @FinnÅrupNielsen yes, that's what I would do. I'm not sure about sentence stress though.